# Как передать value из одной формы в другую?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1.html

```
<html><head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="redirect" action="http://site.ru/test/2.html" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="blablabla" />
<input type="hidden" name="mac" value="$(mac)" />
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
 document.redirect.submit();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

2.html

```
<FORM name="form1" id="form" METHOD="get" action="https://site.ru/test/3.php" >
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="test" VALUE="">
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="mac" VALUE="">
<div id="main_interface" style="display: none">          
        <h2 id="headline" style="font-size:100%">Введите логин и пароль</h2>
          <table >
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                <input id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="Имя пользователя" type="text" value="">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                <input id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Пароль" type="number" value=""> 
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>

                <td id="submit-container" style="padding: none; text-align:center; font-style:italic; vertical-align:top; color:#444">
                  <input class="btn-info" type="submit" name="login" value="Войти">
                </td>
              </tr>   
            </tbody>
          </table>          
</div>
</form>
```

Как передать value из формы 1.html в 2.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно на 2.html добавить этот JS-код:

```js
var mydata = location.search.substring(1);
form1.test.value = mydata.split("&")[0].split("=")[1];
form1.mac.value = mydata.split("&")[1].split("=")[1];
```

Ещё почитайте тут: [Передача и обработка данных в html-файле](https://www.spravkaweb.ru/javascript/sovet/get/)